# Delayed execution in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delayed-execution

Is it possible to start procedure delayed after the calling procedure will end?

```
procedure StartLoop;
begin
  DoSomething;
end;

procedure FormCreate(...);
begin
  if ParamStr(1)='start' then StartLoop;
end;
```

StartLoop will be called **inside** FormCreate, and FormCreate will be waiting, and block further execution not only the of FormCreate itself, but also further procedures executing after it (FormShow, etc.), and form will not show until StartLoop will end.

I need to wait until FormCreate will end, and run StartLoop after that (without using threads).

Comment: There are many many possible ways to achieve this and which is best depends on factors that we can't see. I suspect that your accepted answer based on a timer is probably the worst possible solution.

Comment: Possible dupe: [What is the best way to call a procedure “delayed”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588102/576719)

Comment: What's wrong with timer? In "possible dupe" is no answer (answers to this question are more useful). Don't like using windows messages at all.

Comment: I selected timer precisely because it is simplest, and works in main thread.

Comment: @jsmith, `TThread.ForceQueue` is working in the main thread and can be called from the main thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is using timer.

Let you create `DelayTimer` with needed period set and `Enabled = False` on the form in design time (you can also create it dynamically). Assign event handler for it:

```
  procedure TFormXX.DelayTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
     DelayTimer.Enabled := False;   // works only once
     StartLoop;
  end;
```

in the form intialization routine start this timer:

```
 procedure FormCreate(...);
 begin
   if ParamStr(1)='start' then  
       DelayTimer.Enabled := True; 
 end;
```

Perhaps you want to start the timer later, for example - in the `OnShow`, if your application performs some continuous actions during creation.

Comment: This is risky though because now the procedure runs at some unspecified point in the execution flow.

Comment: @David Heffernan But author did not specified when exactly `DoSomething` could safely start, so I added the last sentence.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using 10.2 Tokyo or later, you can use [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue):

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ParamStr(1) = 'start' then
    TThread.ForceQueue(nil, StartLoop);
end;
```

Otherwise, you can use `PostMessage()` instead:

```
const
  WM_STARTLOOP = WM_USER + 1;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ParamStr(1) = 'start' then
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_STARTLOOP, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMyForm.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_STARTLOOP then
    StartLoop
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

AN other solution could be wrapping your `DoSomething` method into a Task:

```
uses
  System.Threading;

procedure TForm2.DoSomething;
begin
  Sleep(2000);
  Caption := 'Done';
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ParamStr(1) = 'start' then
    TTask.Run(
      procedure
      begin
        DoSomething
      end);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. This will run in main thread or in separate thread? Doing something with VCL is OK from the **DoSomething**, or, because it is separate thread, should not be used?

Comment: In which case, you can use `TThread.Synchronize()` or  `TThread.Queue()` to have the task thread execute code in the main UI thread. But, I would generally recommend using `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()` instead of `TTask` for this. `TTask` is overkill for such a simple task, nit to mention `TTask` is notorioisly buggy in general.